# Load different CSS in application layout based on page type (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

My application has pages of two basic types: forms and tables.

As such, I have two different CSS files, forms.css and tables.css.

In my application layout file (application.html.erb), I'd like to load different stylesheets depending on some sort of flag set in a given view.

For example, `<%= defined?(@tables) : stylesheet_link_tag 'tables' ? stylesheet_link_tag 'forms' %>`.

The above snippet doesn't actually work, but that's what I'm trying to accomplish?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move this to a before_filter in your controller. Keep the view lightweight.

In the view:

```
<%=stylesheet_link_tag @foo %>
```

before_filter in Controller:

```
before_filter :get_css_file

def get_css_file
  @foo = defined?(@tables) ? 'tables' : 'forms'
end
```

I presume you set @tables in your controller, so you might have to adjust your logic, but you get the idea. In fact you already know if it's a table or form page controller, probably, so you'd basically just be setting `@foo` directly: `@foo = 'tables'` etc.

Comment: How'd one go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried a similar thing and it works for me. Your code isn't quite right, perhaps you just need to change it to

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag(defined?(@tables) ? 'tables' : 'forms') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ternary operator syntax is wrong, if that's what you're trying to do. I think you mean this:

```
<%= defined?(@tables) ? stylesheet_link_tag 'tables' : stylesheet_link_tag 'forms' %>
```

The question mark (?) and colon (:) changed places.